How to make the innermost NavigatorPopHandler handle the back gesture on Android with Flutter?
It seems that the back gesture only gets handled by the outermost NavigatorPopHandler.
I would expect the innermost active NavigatorPopHandler to receive the pop request.
Minimal reproducible example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final topKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final nestedKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() => runApp(const NavigatorPopHandlerApp());

class NavigatorPopHandlerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigatorPopHandlerApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: TopNavigator());
  }
}

class TopNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopNavigator({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigatorPopHandler(
      onPop: () => print("trying to pop top navigator!"),
      child: Navigator(
        key: topKey,
        initialRoute: "/initial",
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          if (settings.name == "/initial") {
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NestedNavigator());
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NestedNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedNavigator({super.key});

  static final pattern = RegExp(r"/initial/nested/(?<n>\d+)");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigatorPopHandler(
      onPop: () {
        nestedKey.currentState!.pop();
      },
      child: Navigator(
        key: nestedKey,
        initialRoute: '/initial/nested/1',
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          final name = settings.name ?? '';
          if (pattern.firstMatch(name) case var match?) {
            final n = int.parse(match.namedGroup("n")!);
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CountPage(n));
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CountPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CountPage(this.n, {super.key});

  final int n;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(n.toString()),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/initial/nested/${n + 1}"),
              child: const Text("next page"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Expected behaviour: when doing the back gesture on Android, the innermost NavigatorPopHandler receives the pop request and its onPop is called. The outermost onPop is not called.
(The nested page is popped, showing the previous page, which has its counter decreased by one.)
Actual behaviour: only the outermost onPop gets called. (The page is not changed and the console prints "tryig to pop top navigator".)
How do I make sure the pop gets handled by the innermost navigator?
